# Why [where-on-earth] questions are downvoted heavily?

Tags: discussion

I have asked this question recently: [Where did the Hungarian PM travel to & take this picture?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/168411/where-did-the-hungarian-pm-travel-to-take-this-picture)

Based on the [where-on-earth] [tag's description](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/where-on-earth/info), I think it is a perfectly legitimate question. I looked at the other questions with this tag, [the 3 newest questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/where-on-earth) (excluding mine) with this tag are also downvoted.

I might very well be missing something. What is wrong with these questions & how to improve mine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have had too many low quality 'where on earth' photo questions so now people here are very critical about such questions.

On top of that, the photo you ask about does not have a lot of recognizable details, for that reason downvotes are not unlikely.

On the other hand, it now shows two downvotes against two upvotes. That is not 'heavily downvoted' in my book, but I have to admit that I have not checked voting history.

If you add more details, why you look for the location, what you already know and where and how you got the photo, you stand a better chance on a good reception.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive feedback!

Comment: @zabop I would also add that the original post had the word "cringewarning" in it, which made it politically charged. I've removed it since but this might be why some downvoted it originally. In general we try not to politicize anything on Travel.SE.

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Comment: That's a good point.